# Eclipse Build Workspace Large Number of Errors and Warnings

Tags: java, eclipse, workspace

Currently running Eclipse Indigo with jre1.7

I am running into a performance problem with the save time of my project. I am writing a rather large application with many classes that runs perfectly with executed. However, every build reports over 1000 errors and 1500 warnings. I personally only count maybe 50 warnings total and no errors anywhere. This doesnt seem to impede the execution, but it makes the compile time too large (over a minute every time I resave). Is there a way to find these errors that occur during compile time? They do not show in "problems" or "error log" either.

Please tell me if there is any more information required as I am not sure what is pertinent.

Comment: Do you have mutiple projects and your build order specified correctly? (Window->Preferences)->(General->Workspace->Build Order)

Comment: I have only one project in my workspace. I have 4 separate referenced libraries (dom4j-1.5.1.jar, ooxml-schemas-1.0.jar, xmlbeans-2.4.0-sources.jar, and commons-lang3-3.1.jar). These jars are in a folder "Reference Libraries" and are in my buildpath (Java Build Path > all listed there)

Comment: Maybe you should update to Eclipse Juno.......

Comment: I cannot see how this solution affects anything... but ty for your input.

Comment: Does the Build Order Matter? Java Build Path-> Order and Export : ...src , JRE System Library [JavaSE-1.7], JRE System Library [jre7], ooxml-schemas-1.0.jar, xmlbeans-2.4.0-sources.jar, dom4j-1.5.1.jar, commons-lang3-3.1.jar. none of them are checkmarked cept the src folder

Comment: You have *2* JRE System Library entries in the Build Path?

Comment: yes, will this create problems? I wasnt sure which one was correct when i installed (JavaSE-1.7 or jre7). Can anyone tell me the difference's? Thanks.

Comment: I removed the extra library (jre7) but it did not solve anything. Any more ideas/info would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ok, I think I found the problem, the referenced library (xmlbeans-2.4.0-sources.jar) was incorrect and I thus replaced it with (xmlbeans-2.4.0.jar). NOW it shows all the thousands of errors (all related to invalid imports on org.apache.commons*). I do not have this in my biuldpath, where do I get the jar for this? All i can find is a zip file, but adding the zip does not fix anything.